# INVALID_FILEHANDLE Error

Tags: oracle, unix

I am getting error from oracle package in unix ksh script. The error is "INVALID_FILEHANDLE" could you please help up to resolve the below error.

Thanks and Regards,
Kiran

```
Erreur ! INVALID_FILEHANDLE
BEGIN p02ik.p02ip('/prep/dst/ins/tmp','/prep/dst/ins/log','PDSDI202.tmp','dstins_p02_202.log'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20226: C'est le code de retour ==> Erreur Grave
ORA-06512: at "DATASTORE.P02IK", line 710
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

---

Full Log

---

```
toracle-exvokkes /prep/dst/ins/prog/scripts $ dstins_p02_202.ksh
+ date
+ echo ********     INTERFACE : p02     ******** Tue Feb 25 13:00:35 GMT 2014
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ RC=0
+ /admin/checkbase.ksh datastore/dtstr@dsprep
La chaine de connexion est  datastore/dtstr@dsprep
datastore/dtstr@dsprep
slash trouve

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production on Tue Feb 25 13:00:36 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Connected.

SYSDATE
---------
25-FEB-14

Disconnected from Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production
Le code retour SQL est :  0
+ RC=0
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ cd /prep/dst/ins/ifile
+ + ls PDSDI202 PDSDI202.20140221153315
LIST_FIC=PDSDI202
PDSDI202.20140221153315
+ echo Liste de fichiers a traiter : PDSDI202
PDSDI202.20140221153315
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ ls -l PDSDI202 PDSDI202.20140221153315
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo fichier traite : PDSDI202
+ tee -a /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
fichier traite : PDSDI202
+ CONTINUER=N
+ [ N = N ]
+ + awk  { print $1 }
+ du -k PDSDI202
TAILLE_1=64
+ echo TAILLE_1=64
+ tee -a /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
TAILLE_1=64
+ sleep 20
+ + du -k PDSDI202
+ awk  { print $1 }
TAILLE_2=64
+ tee -a /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo TAILLE_2=64
TAILLE_2=64
+ [ 64 != 64 ]
+ [ 64 = 64 ]
+ echo la copie du fichier PDSDI202 est terminee
+ tee -a /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
la copie du fichier PDSDI202 est terminee
+ CONTINUER=Y
+ [ Y = N ]
+ mv /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202
mv: 0653-405 /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 and /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 are identical.
+ [ -f /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 ]
+ echo LE FICHIER /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 EXISTE
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ ls -l /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ [ -s /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 ]
+ echo LE FICHIER /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 N'EST PAS VIDE
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
+ mv /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02_202.log /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02_202.log20140225130058
mv: 0653-401 Cannot rename /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02_202.log to /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02_202.log20140225130058:
             A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
+ + echo PDSDI202
+ sed s/\(.*\)/\1\.tmp/
F_FICENT_TMP=PDSDI202.tmp
+ awk  {
        if (substr($0, 1, 6) == "EDI_DC")
           { print($0); }
        else
           { printf("%s\n", substr($0, 1, 55));
             printf("%s\n", substr($0, 56, (length($0)-55))); }
      }
+ 0< /prep/dst/ins/ifile/PDSDI202 1> /prep/dst/ins/tmp/PDSDI202.tmp
+ [ -f /prep/dst/ins/tmp/PDSDI202.tmp ]
+ :
+ date
+ echo DEBUT CHARGEMENT FICHIER /prep/dst/ins/tmp/PDSDI202 : Tue Feb 25 13:00:58 GMT 2014
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ sqlplus -s datastore/dtstr@dsprep
+ 0<<
echo sqlplus
set serverout on
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
whenever oserror  exit oscode
SELECT 'p02ik.p02ip' from DUAL ;
-- ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE ;
EXECUTE p02ik.p02ip('/prep/dst/ins/tmp','/prep/dst/ins/log','PDSDI202.tmp','dstins_p02_202.log');
commit work;
exit sql.sqlcode;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo sqlpl..." - rest of line ignored.

'P02IK.P02I
-----------
p02ik.p02ip

Starting..
BEGIN1
/prep/dst/ins/log
dstins_p02_202.log
/prep/dst/ins/tmp
PDSDI202.tmp
ENDBEGIN1
Erreur ! INVALID_FILEHANDLE
BEGIN p02ik.p02ip('/prep/dst/ins/tmp','/prep/dst/ins/log','PDSDI202.tmp','dstins_p02_202.log'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20226: C'est le code de retour ==> Erreur Grave
ORA-06512: at "DATASTORE.P02IK", line 710
ORA-06512: at line 1


+ RC=2
+ echo INTEGRATION  DU FICHIER /prep/dst/ins/tmp/PDSDI202 : ERREURS BLOQUANTES
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo REGARDER /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02_202.log
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo RC=2
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ date
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ echo
+ 1>> /prep/dst/ins/log/dstins_p02.log
+ exit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have some wrapper to invoke the `UTL_FILE()` methods, bit difficult to confirm what theissue could be.

Actually `UTL_FILE` expects the input/output file directory to be predefined directory name as appearing in the dictionary table `all_directories` (column directory_name)

```
 BEGIN
 p02ik.p02ip('/prep/dst/ins/tmp',
             '/prep/dst/ins/log',
             'PDSDI202.tmp',
             'dstins_p02_202.log');
 END;
```

I just wonder where you specify the directory name as available in [ALL_DIRECTORIES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1049.htm) table.

[INVALID_FILE_HANDLE](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/bipack/ch06_02.htm) error, would occur, when the UTL_FILE handler is referring a invalid directory that is either unavailable, or available but not accessible to oracle instance.

Other reason, is you didnt specify the directory name as mentioned in all_dictionary table.

To. summarise,
1) make sure, the directory name should indirectly referred from all_directory not should not be explicitly given
2) oracle process should have read n wrote access to the filesystem specified above.
3) space is available in the file system

[An Example is Here](http://psoug.org/snippet/UTL_FILE-file-write-to-file-example_538.htm)